# Could not find Javascript runtime after installing execjs on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, javascript

After installed execjs with `gem install execjs`, still get `cound not find javascript runtime` when running `rails console`. Do I still need to install node.js after execjs?

Thanks so much.

Comment: the error disappeared after installing node.js.

Comment: other js runtime should be OK as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to you Gemfile

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

or just install this gem

```
gem install therubyracer
```